# Finding the character "^" using regex

Tags: java, regex, negation

I'm trying to define a regex pattern that searches for a caret character, but since `^` is used for negation, I'm not sure how to define the pattern. I'm trying to make the program find a string that is a letter then a caret then a number (as you may have guessed, this is a mathematical term), such as `"x^23"`. This is the line I tried:

```
String caseFour = "[a-zA-Z]" + "^" + "\\d+";
```

It's not working. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape that character also since it is a character of [special](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) meaning.

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]\\^\\d+";
```